# Angular 7 (Change)-Function on Input type Date does not work, but why is the format wrong?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-input

I am trying to update the date via key input. I also need the selected date to be assigned to a property of my object.
Here is my following code:

```
<input type="date" [value]="dateTime()"  (change)="setDate($event)"/>
```

The dateTime-function returns the date, which is stored in my object, if it is existing:

```
dateTime()
   if(this.info.sDate != ""){
     let date = this.info.sDate; //of format DD.MM.YYYY
     let year = date.substring(0,4);
     let month = date.substring(4,6);
     let day = date.substring(6,8);
     date = year + "-" + month + '-' + day;
     return date; // now of the format YYYY-MM-DD as needed
   } else {
     let today = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    return today; // if not existing, then return the date of today
   } 
  }
```

Now issues appears, when I am trying to set a new date:

```
  setDate(e){
    this.info.sDate= e.target.value;
    }
```

I try to assign every change on the date to the property `info.sDate`of my object.
I get the warning: `platform-browser.js:1133 The specified value "2020--0-1-" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".`although I do not understand why.

Do anyone can help me?

Comment: how have you declared `this.info.sDate` in component?

Comment: Via API Call, the ```this.data.getOrdByID(this.id).subscribe(data => {
     this.info = data;
   })``` Strangely it works if I pick a date the second time. The first time the format error appears, then the normal picked date. But tipping the date via key input just does not work after all.

Comment: can you provide stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

```
let year = date.substring(6,10);
let month = date.substring(3,5);
let day = date.substring(0,2);
```

Your substring was giving: 10.0-1.-20 the above will give: 2020-01-10

Answer (score 0):

You could cause yourself a lot of problems if you splice the user entered date like this. The format could change depending on the users locale.

One way you could tackle this would be to use three different input boxes, one for each element of the date (Day, Month, Year).

Then you could do something like the following.

```
let date = moment(`${this.day}-${this.month}-${this.year}`, "DD-MM-YYYY");
```